# remove common values from an array using another array in php

Tags: php, arrays

The idea is to remove just the unique same values not all the same values
Example:

```
Array_1 = (1,1,4,5,4,5);
Array_2 = (5,4,5);
```

Desired output

```
(1,1,4)
```

I didn't find the solution using `array_diff()` and `array_intersect()`

Comment: number 4 is in array_2 how you want the difference?

Comment: There is two '4' in the first one (Array_1). As in the second one we found just one '4', it must be kept. If the same number of '4' is in both arrays, we dont display it in the output. ok ?

Comment: If you have to keep the order of "5,4,5", then you may concat the array to string and then make comparison.

Comment: What would be the output for `[1,1,4,5,4,5,5,4,5]` and `[5,4,5]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
$a1 = [1,1,4,5,4,5];
$a2 = [5,4,5];

foreach ($a2 as $item) {
    $key = array_search($item, $a1);
    if (false !== $key) {
        unset($a1[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($a1);
```

Optionally, you can apply `array_values` to reindex `$a1` after `foreach`.

Answer (score -1):

As @Phil commented you may use string instead.

```
$a1 = [1,1,4,5,4,5];
$a2 = [5,4,5];

$stringA1 = implode(',', $a1);
$stringA2 = implode(',', $a2);
$resultString = trim(str_replace($stringA2,'', $stringA1), ',');

$resultArray = explode(',', $resultString);
```

Comment: Your result contains an empty value due to the leftover comma.

Comment: If your array values were in different orders, this approach would not necessarily work.

Comment: Yes I missed to trim the last comma.

Comment: Because his question is to remove the matching order

Comment: @Sat that's an assumption on your part. The question requires clarification.  It is at best ambiguous.

Comment: Yes true it's ambiguous. But that's what I interpreted it